# SQL request in powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell-2.0

I have made a powershell script to reset sql session, it works on a colleague set, but not on mine :

```
add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
add-pssnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100 
 $SQLUsername = 'usename'
 $SQLInstance = "servername";
 $SQLPassword2 = "******"
 $SQLQuery = 'select getdate()'
Invoke-SQLCmd -Query $SQLQuery -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword2 | Format-Table -Autosize
```

I have an error message telling me "add-PSSnapin : no componant register in powershell". I suppose it's because dll for SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 and SqlServerProviderSnapin100 are not installed. Can somebody tell me how I suppose to install it ?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server snap-ins are installed by installing SQL Server Management Tools version 2008 or higher.